# SQL query merge rows if the date is same else dont

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to work on a query and need assitance

Here is my table values

table 1

```
class_Y_distributionFactor  class_I_distributionFactor  class_L_distributionFactor  class_N_distributionFactor  class_R6_distributionFactor StartDate
NULL    0.0745199999999997  NULL    NULL    NULL    2014-12-19 00:00:00.000
NULL    NULL    NULL    0.0647900000000003  NULL    2014-12-19 00:00:00.000
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.0722000000000005  2014-12-19 00:00:00.000
```

Output

```
class_Y_distributionFactor  class_I_distributionFactor  class_L_distributionFactor  class_N_distributionFactor  class_R6_distributionFactor                                 StartDate
NULL                    0.0745199999999997                  NULL                    0.0647900000000003                          0.0722000000000005                      2014-12-19 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Seems like a simple aggregate query grouping on the date. The question of course is which value do you pick if there are values in multiple rows. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit vague in my opinion as there are different approaches I can think of but would only be suitable with more detail in what is to be accomplished and what data you are working with (the sample you gave may allow for one approach but not for another)

Some things to look at:

1. Pivot: Using the pivot you can merge on the single column and spread the data off but with the sample data you gave I think the second option is better
2. Case: This can be used together with a group by clause to determine which values you would like to show
3. SubQueries: Based on your variances you may need to run subqueries to get the job don

Again if you need a proper answer (at least from me), you need to be a bit more specific in your scenario. What I can do is show you a fiddle that has the result you want which is here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8232/4

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the vague question.I solved it using aggregate function sumgroup by date..

I think I clicked too early.